# Adding HTML from an internal file to a Web Part on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have developed a SharePoint Web Part where I have an iframe that I need to load with several pages depend on different values.

For instance, I have this files

- file1.html
- file2.html
- file3.html

And I need to pass the path of one of this elements to an iframe

Where can I put this files and How can I retrieve the right path of this pages?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the html files in a library and set the iframe url dynamically.

```
$('#iframeId').attr('src', url)
```

Comment: HI @Lee_MSFT, I think that I need it should be more easy, I only want to obtain a relative path from an internal file inside my Web Part. I don 't want to create libraries to put this files because from my point of view is an unsense.